# Need Address Book Access. Where is the PLIST to enable this?

Tags: ios, iphone, plist, springboard, frank

I'm working using the Cucumber-Frank testing Framework which automates BDD Tests for iPhones. I want my device to be able to access a user's contacts, much like how I get their location on launch from SpringBoard.

Now, for location, I go to `/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Library/Caches` and copy one of the plists into my environment in `Frank`.

Thus, I have Location Access turned on right now.

Now, I want to get Access to Contacts as well. I can't seem to figure out a way to do this, or a plist that I can add. On doing : `grep -r "contacts" *`, I got a result -

```
Binary file com.apple.mobile.installation~iPhone.plist matches
```

However, I can't find any Boolean Variable or so inside. Can someone direct me as to what the correct plist or variable it might be?

This page : (http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/address-book-file-locations/) says it might be at `com.apple.AddressBook.plist`, which DOES NOT EXIST in the new iOS.